# how to load word vector model binary file of glove ( cooccurence.bin )?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I am using the GloVe nlp tools for calculate the cosine distance of two words: word1 and word2 .

I already trained my model and got the cooccurance.bin file by runing:

```
./demo.sh
```

What my question is, how should I load the coocurrence.bin file?

I had search by google there is no any clue about this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the bin file using glove_python.

```
pip install glove_python
```

Example to load the model:

```
from glove import Glove
g = Glove.load('glove.model')
```